# Is there a way to delete parts that meet the conditions in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to erase all parts of notepad++ between certain symbols.
For example, if there's a phrase that says [], I want to erase it all, whether it's [apple] or [basketball].
I have nothing to do with coding, so could you help me?

Comment: follow the step in that links : https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/notepad-macros-example/

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that could help you?

It explains find and replace with a regex.

https://superuser.com/questions/1003958/how-do-i-delete-text-between-2-characters

Ofcourse you need to change some things like:

Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or Ctrl + H)

Set "Find what" to [(.*?)]

Set "Replace with" to [] OR LEAVE BLANK

Enable "Regular expression"

Click "Replace All"

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace with regular expression in replace dialog
Find  ([[^]]+])
Replace  []
Select "Regular expression" radiobutton
Click Replace All